# Html.TextAreaFor<> ASP.MET MVC 5 Cursor Position

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

The code for my TextBoxAreaFor<> text area (for some reason) puts the cursor at the end of the text area and not at the start like a TextBoxFor<> does. How do I get the cursor to be placed at correct position i.e. At beginning of text area?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.IncidentDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentDescription)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no way to set the initial cursor position for `<textarea>` in pure HTML. You'll need to use a client script to call `input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);`

Comment: I'm not using any jQuery to set the cursor at the moment. Do I must? It should really start at the beginning of the text area